# Database error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'Cursor .getScene()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.database.Cursor
>   com.example.munna.homeauto.DatabaseCreation.getScene()' on a null
>   object reference

```
public class Server extends Activity {

    DatabaseCreation myDb;
    int i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.scenario);

        myDb = new DatabaseCreation(this);

    }

    public void server_check() {
        System.out.println("client");
        int j;
        int k;
        Cursor scene = myDb.getScene();//unfortunetly stops when cursor comes to this step
        while (scene.moveToNext()) {
            System.out.println("client 1");
            for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                scene.getString(i);
                System.out.println("client 2");
                // my code for server message 
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: this is my requirement.i am creating a new class for generating a server message.in this class server checks databse and gets the data.everything is ok but when cursor goes to Cursor scene = myDb.getScene(); app unfortunetly stops. even i initialized database properly..i am not getting the what is the issue going on here please help me..thanq

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sence.hasNext()) {
while (scene.moveToNext()) {
    System.out.println("client 1");
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(scene.getString(i));
       }
    }
}
```

Good Luck :)

Comment: The error is thrown before the Cursor is used

Comment: i didn't get you..what does that if condition do..